# ngx-moveable Angular trying to add a button

Tags: angular

Trying to add a button as the demo:
[image]

I added the following code:

```
<ngx-moveable #moveable ... [ables]="customAble"
```

and

```
    customAble = {
        name: "customAble",
        always: true,
        props: {},
        events: {},
        render(moveable, React) {
            alert('1');
            const { renderPoses } = moveable.state;
            return `
             <button
        onClick={() => {
          alert("Delete");
        }}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${renderPoses[1][0]}px, ${renderPoses[1][1]}px) translateZ(-50px)',
          zIndex: 10000
        }}>Delete</button>
            `;
        },
    };
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

for it working, needed:
`[ables]="[Editable]"  [props]="({ editable: true })"`

and the code:

```
    Editable = {
        name: "editable",
        props: [],
        events: [],
        render: (moveable: MoveableManagerInterface<any, any>, React: Renderer) => {
            // React.createElement() ...
            const rect = moveable.getRect();
            const {pos2} = moveable.state;
            const EditableViewer = moveable.useCSS("div", `
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            will-change: transform;
            transform-origin: 0px 0px;
        }
        .custom-button {
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
            background: #4af;
            border-radius: 4px;
            appearance: none;
            border: 0;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
            `);
            return React.createElement(EditableViewer, {
                key: "editable-viewer",
                className: "moveable-editable",
                style: {
                    transform: `translate(${pos2[0]}px, ${pos2[1]}px) rotate(${rect.rotation}deg) translate(10px)`
                }
            }, [
                "\n            ",
                React.createElement("button", {
                    className: "custom-button",
                    onClick: () => {
                        alert("+");
                    }
                }, [
                    "+"
                ]),
                "\n            ",
                React.createElement("button", {
                    className: "custom-button",
                    onClick: () => {
                        alert("-");
                    }
                }, [
                    "-"
                ]),
                "\n        "
            ]);


        }

    } as const
```